# Karl Simrock's Nibelungenlied translation

Tags: sentence-structure, literature

I am reading the Nibelungenlied's translation by Karl Simrock. One of the first few verses reads:

> Die Minnigliche [Kriemhild] *lieben* brachte keinen Scham,
>   Um die [Kriemhild] viel Recken warben, niemand war ihr [Kriemhild] gram.

I would like to know to proper syntax for *lieben*. It seems to me to be an infinitive, in which case the sentence would read: *to love the lovely lady brought no shame*.

However, I would expect the preposition *zu* before it, as I was taught, as in *die Minnigliche zu lieben*.

Is my reading correct? If so, should I expect to see more "flying infinitives" like this? If not, would anyone explain the syntax?

Comment: I think you are right, except that _zu_ in connection with infinitives can't be considered a preposition.

Comment: This kind of translation is no modern German. It uses a lot of old words and constructions. The "zu"  is lacking, most probably to get the rhythm right. You should look out for a second translation.

Comment: It should also be considered, this is no modern text. There will most possibly be structures or sentences that sound queer regarding today's German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reading is correct, *lieben* is an infinitive, or, to be more exact: a "free infinitive" which doesn't use *zu*.

Nevertheless, *zu lieben* would also be correct in this context, i.e. "*Die Minnigliche [Kriemhild] zu lieben[,] brachte keine Scham*". One could also imagine a permutation, something like "*Es brachte keine Scham, die minnigliche Kriemhild zu lieben*", where *es* and *zu* would be indispensable.